# Expand an expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have the following expression (string) in javascript:

```
var my_expr = "(2*(A||B&&C))&&(3*D)";
```

How do I make to get something like this:

```
(2*A||2*B&&2*C)&&(3*D)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: couldn't you just write the bottom one instead ?

Comment: No, I can't, because I got this expression through the response by another api

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the expression into an abstract expression tree. This is not the easiest task but neither is it impossible. Next thing, you'll have to implement some algebraic properties, especially [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property), which you are showing here. Lastly, you have to express which rules to apply on which sub-tree of the expression.

Once you've done all this for the general case, it will be TRIVIAL to apply it to this and all similar cases you may encounter.

[Primer on expression trees in Javascript](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/08/math-evaluator-in-javascript-part1.html)

**EDIT: You have to go through expression trees, there is no shortcut, because it's the only way algebraic properties can be applied correctly for all cases**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) the string:

```
> var str = "4*5";
> eval(str);
20
```

There's countless resources all over the internet about why `eval` is a dangerous thing to use. This is particularly true if you're obtaining the string from another source. If there are any alternatives to this, I would recommend using them.